# Why does Prolog length function returns sum in form 1+1+...?

Tags: prolog

This is the length function:

```
len([], 0).

len([H|T], N + 1) :-
    len(T, N).
```

When I query

```
?- len([3,4,5], X).
```

Why do I get `X = 0 + 1 + 1 + 1` instead of `X = 3`?

Comment: Prolog doesn't evaluate arithmetic operators by default. Sounds odd, but this allows you to write predicates that reason aboit  such operators. Only specific Prolog operator that performance such evaluation, such as `is/2` or arithmetic comparators.

Answer (score 0):

The + is defined as an (infix) operator.

When you have an occurrence of `A+B` in your code, that gets translated into `+(A,B)`, but it is never evaluated.

The term `+(1,1)` is just another term, like `foo(a,b)`, and is not interpreted in any special way (i.e. performing addition whatsoever). For example you could use the term `x/y` to represent pairs of numbers, such as the coordinates of a chessboard, and pass the term `x/y` around without ever computing the numerical result of the mathematical expression `x/y`.

You can verify the true nature of `+`, by using `display/1` in a prolog prompt:

```
?- display(1+1).
+(1,1)
true.

?- display(1+2*3-4).
-(+(1,*(2,3)),4)
true.
```

In order to compute the **arithmetic evaluation** of that, you use `is/2`:

```
?- X is 1+1.
X = 2.
```

and, since `1+1` is the binary term `+(1,1)`, this also works:

```
?- X is +(1,1).
X = 2.
```

and since `is/2` is also an infix operator, i.e. `A is B` gets expanded to `is(A,B)`, this also works:

```
?- is(X, +(1,1)).
X = 2.
```

To fix your code, you would create a new variable `N1`, and use `N1 is N+1` to compute the addition:

```
len([], 0).

len([H|T], N1) :-
    len(T, N), N1 is N+1.
```